# Sum of total scores odds will end even or odd

Tags: probability

Friend and i are betting on the ending total scores of basketball game, he says odds are greater it will end with an even sum, i say the odds are equal. Who is right?

Comment: Since 2-pointers don't change the parity of the score, you only need to look at 3-pointers and free throws (1 point). I'm not sure about something like the NBA, but if it was a bunch of primary school kids playing basketball I'd bet on even since I doubt I'd see that many 3-pointers/free throws scoring.

Comment: To sum up the answers below, either you're right, or you're both wrong. Half a win for you?

Answer (score 5):

In theory @gev is correct, but I don't think it's a reasonable assumption that it's equally likely for either team to score odd vs even.

I analyzed every NCAA game since 2010 http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/play-index/tourney.cgi and got

Odd: 262
Even: 222

So 54% odd.

If I had to guess which is more probable I'd say odd. Suppose that team A scored X points.  Then team B can score anything BUT X, meaning there's one less possibility to get an even sum.

Comment: Two teams getting the same score means the sum will be even... and since they can't get the same score, that's just one less way to get an even sum...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry.

Comment: np... my explanation prolly wasn't as clear as it could have been...

Comment: Well, actually they could get the same last digit of the score, which really is the determining factor: one team can have 80 and the other gets 70, so there is still the same probability for even or odd. Yes?

Comment: @DanielHayden no. The point is that if team A gets 80, team B cannot get 80. It can get 79,81,78,82,77,83, etc. and indeed 70, as you say, but it cannot get 80. So within any symmetrical distribution of scores deviating from 80, the there is a slight bias towards the odd numbers. That seems to make some sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

1. even + even = even
2. odd + odd = even
3. even + odd = odd
4. odd + even = odd

Assuming both teams' chances are equal to score even and odd, the chances for sum are equal too. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

well, in a real situation I am not sure the probability may be actually computed.

If we say that the results of a basketball game are a couple of positive integers less than a fixed value (say, 1000) with the only constraint that they are different, consider the score $N$ of the winner. The loser may have scored with the same probability a value from 0 to $N-1$; if $N$ is even, the odds are even, but if $N$ is odd it is more probable that the sum is odd.

Answer (score -2):

even = even + even

even = odd + odd

*i.e.*: If both are similar (both are even or odd) then the answer is even.

But if both are different then the answer is odd.

odd = even + odd

odd =  odd + even

Comment: Please don't use all-caps. Also, your answer doesn't add anything new to those already given. It may be best to delete it.

Answer (score -2):

When u are betting odd and even
u have to bet in calculated steps..
Instead to bet on the total score odd or even,break into the 4 quarters using the backup betting system. With this u can earn up 45%
of all your stake..

1 Quarter odd $1×1.90
2 Quarter odd $3×1.90
3 Quarter odd $9×1.90
4 Quarter odd $27×1.90..

U only up your stake if the previous bet is lost..

If u have the bankroll to supported this odd and even betting system u can never lost...hope this helps.